# Using media queries to interchange content on Foundation 5

Tags: media-queries, interchange, zurb-foundation-5

thanks for helping me out.

I'm using Foundation 5 and I can't seem to work out how to properly interchange content.

For mobile resolutions I have designed 10 accordions and in a duplicated index.html file I have created vertical tabs that are working for desktop resolutions. On the foundation 5 documentation, the details around using interchange content are specific to images, which become interactive for larger resolutions.

How do I setup my code so I can display accordions on mobile and vertical tabs on desktop?

Would be greatly appreciated if someone can assist with this.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Since accordion and tabs have a different markup, what I suggest is to use visibility classes, I don't thing interchange will work and also you can save some js using only css (you can find them here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html).